# Sidekiq - Get job running a specific queue (via method call)

Tags: sidekiq

I saw the Sidekiq allows me to assign a worker to a specific queue. What I want is to be able to tell the worker during enqueueing which queue to run in (vs. setting this globally on the worker).

Is this possible?

The case scenario: During my daily update jobs for my data, I want to enqueue this method in a low priority queue. When a new user comes into the system and I want to update his data immediately I want to call the same method but run it in a priority queue.

Do I have to create 2 different workers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, just use the lower-level `Sidekiq::Client` API instead of `perform_async`:

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => MyWorker, 'args' => [1, 2, 3], 'queue' => 'low')
```